# Ray casting intersection with infinite plane with normal and offset

Tags: math, graphics, raytracing, raycasting

I have an Infinite Plane and I know its Normal and Offset.
Now, I want to know if a Ray Casting ray is intersecting with this Infinite Plane.

How can I know that?

Answer (score 3):

Let the ray be described as *a*+λ∙*b*, i.e. starting at point *a* and going in direction *b*. Let the plane be described as *n*∙*x*=*d*, i.e. the set of points *x* which have the same offset *d*, measured in direction of *n*.

Now simply plug one into the other:
*n*∙(*a*+λ∙*b*) = *d*
*n*∙*a*+λ∙*n*∙*b* = *d*
λ∙*n*∙*b* = *d* − *n*∙*a*
λ = (*d* − *n*∙*a*)/(*n*∙*b*)

If the λ computed in this fashion is positive, then the ray will intersect the plane.